# Cannot run program “g++”: Launching failed - Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, mingw

I have to do some project with OpenCV. I downloaded Eclipse, upgraded it with CDT, instaled MinGW and linked OpenCV libraries. But still I cannot launch even single program!

```
01:27:48 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Detector ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\opencv\\build\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\VC\\include" "-IC:\\MinGW\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.8.1\\include" "-IC:\\MinGW\\mingw32\\include" "-IC:\\MinGW\\include" "-IC:\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv" "-IC:\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv2" "-IC:\\opencv\\include" "-IC:\\opencv\\include\\opencv" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\main.o" "..\\src\\main.cpp" 
Cannot run program "g++": Launching failed

Error: Program "g++" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\binC:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer\binaries\php\php_runningversion;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\opencv\build\bin\;C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\;C:\opencv\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\;C:\eclipseCPP\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\opencv\build\bin\;C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\;C:\opencv\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\;C:\eclipseCPP]
```

Could somebody tell me, where is the problem? (I work on Windows)

Comment: Can you run `g++` in some command window? And `c:\MinGW\bin\g++`? Did you consider installing and using Linux? And you don't need Eclipse (but just some editor) to use `g++` !

Comment: do you know in which folder your `g++` executable is located? You need to add it to the `PATH` environment variable

Comment: Where it can be in Windows? Or should I download something?

Comment: Any ideas with MinGW?

Comment: @pavlucco: please check the `how to` page of `MinGW` on how to download the `gcc-g++`: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW

Answer (score 1):

Summary of the various answers:

1. Get `gcc-g++` `bin` and `dll`: Please refer to the how to page of MinGW for gcc-g++: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW
2. Check `g++.exe` location and add it to your environment variable `PATH` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

After installing MinGW, you still need install gcc and g++ compilers in MinGW.